# Running a script and get it alive after a SSH disconnection (like a broken pipe) without forcing it in background

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

If I got a bash script that it's something like this

```
#!/bin/bash -p

echo "PART A PID $$" >> "txt$$.txt";

for ((a=1; a<=10; a++))
do
  sleep 1
  echo "PART B$a" >> "txt$$.txt";
done
                                                                                                                                       
echo "PART C" >> "txt$$.txt";
```

I know that `./script.sh & disown` can prevent a script from being stopped when SSH exits, but I want to achieve that without needing to put the script in the background.

```
PART A
PART B1
PART B2
PART B3
PART B4
PART B5
PART B6
PART B7
PART B8
PART B9
PART B10
PART C
```

and getting an output like this.

I want to wait for the cycle to get an ordered output.

**Note (i don't want nohup)**

**EDIT**

I'm doing this because I want to start more than one of this.

If i do something like

```
#!/bin/bash -p

(
echo "PART A PID $$" >> "txt$$.txt";
for ((a=1; a<=10; a++))
do
  sleep 1
  echo "PART B$a" >> "txt$$.txt";
done
echo "PART C" >> "txt$$.txt";
) & disown
```

the PID changes. In this way if I want to stop the process i can't get the original referrer of the pid.

I want to know if there's something simple to put at the bottom, without upset all the code

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement some auto-backgrounding logic for the script, although your 'I want to wait' seems to contradict this. What have you tried?

Comment: "It sounds like you want to implement some auto-backgrounding logic for the script, although your 'I want to wait' seems to contradict this. What have you tried?" Nothing. I dont have idea how to do it. I added only `done & disown` after the for, but in this way it don't respect the output order.

Comment: A double-fork (which changes the PID) _is_ how self-backgrounding/daemonization is done, even in C.

Comment: To "disown" a process from a parent is to remove it from the job table _tracked by that parent shell_. That table (unlike the operating system's process table) is part of the parent shell's process state, stored in that parent shell's memory. It's not something the OS as a whole controls, and thus not something a separate process has the ability to directly reach in and modify.

Comment: BTW, it's bad form to put `>> "txt$$.txt"` in your program more than once -- every time you do that redirection it re-opens the output file. Consider putting `exec >"txt$$.txt"` just once at the top of your script; that'll make _all_ future stdout go to the named file.

Comment: The other thing is that `disown` doesn't actually _do anything useful_ in a noninteractive shell -- job control is a feature that's only on by default in interactive shells. You _can_ call `disown` in a script executing in a noninteractive shell, but it's utterly pointless to do so.

Comment: @Charles Duffy "BTW, it's bad form to put >> "txt$$.txt" in your program more than once -- every time you do that redirection it re-opens the output file. Consider putting exec >"txt$$.txt" just once at the top of your script; that'll make all future stdout go to the named file." >> interesting

Comment: "disown from the inside and also wait for the end" -- I'm also not sure that even makes sense. You can only disown something (remove it from the job table) if it was in the job table in the first place (which is to say, if it was a background process); foreground processes aren't ever _in_ the job table to start with. And something where the parent waits for it to execute... is a foreground process, thus not in the job table in the first place, so trying to _remove_ it from the job table makes no sense.

Comment: @Charles Duffy "The other thing is that disown doesn't actually do anything useful in a noninteractive shell -- job control is a feature that's only on by default in interactive shells. You can call disown in a script executing in a noninteractive shell, but it's utterly pointless to do so". Not agree with so. If I use ssh and I've got a "broken pipe" I want the same that the process has to be still running

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether you're in the job table or not; `disown` has no effect on it.

Comment: "I'm also not sure that even makes sense. You can only disown something (remove it from the job table) if it was in the job table in the first place (which is to say, if it was a background process); foreground processes aren't ever in the job table to start with. And something where the parent waits for it to execute... is a foreground process, thus not in the job table in the first place, so trying to remove it from the job table makes no sense." @Charles Duff Are you here for criticism or to help me?!?!! 

Comment: If you want to keep running if your SSH session dies, the thing to do is make sure you redirect stdin, stdout and stderr so none of them are going through that copy of ssh; and then clear the `SIGHUP` handles with the `trap` keyword.

Comment: I'm trying to _understand your problem_. Having the problem explained in a way that lets me understand it is a prerequisite to helping you.

Comment: @Charles Duffy "That has nothing to do with whether you're in the job table or not; disown has no effect on it." -- Not agree. With the disown the process it goes also id i disconnect

Comment: @Charles Duffy "If you want to keep running if your SSH session dies, the thing to do is make sure you redirect stdin, stdout and stderr so none of them are going through that copy of ssh; and then clear the SIGHUP handles with the trap keyword." Could be good. But like U can read i was searching for a simple thing, not 3221 lines of code

Comment: "With the disown the process it goes also id i disconnect" -- if I read those words for their literal meaning, they agree with me -- you're saying that _even with_ disown the process still exits on disconnect, meaning that disown doesn't fix the problem. Which is true.

Comment: `disown` takes a process out of the job table, so if an interactive shell is going to try to propagate a `SIGHUP` to those jobs it's running, taking something out of the table will prevent that; _but_ a program that's still attached to a now-dead file descriptor for stdin or stderr is still going to get a SIGPIPE the moment it tries to read or write from those descriptors.

Comment: Redirecting all three of stdin/stdout/stderr and then arranging to ignore SIGHUP _is_ simple, and it's how this has always been done. It's _exactly_ what `nohup` does, f/e. It's two lines, one for the `exec` and one for the `trap`. Nothing hard about it.

Comment: ""With the disown the process it goes also id i disconnect" -- if I read those words for their literal meaning, they agree with me -- you're saying that even with disown the process still exits on disconnect, meaning that disown doesn't fix the problem. Which is true ..... job table, so if an interactive shell is going to try to propagate a SIGHUP to those jobs it's running ..... attached to a now-dead file descriptor for stdin or stderr is still going to get a SIGPIPE the moment it tries to read or write from those descriptors" SIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

Comment: Yelling "SIMPLE" at me isn't going to make the facts simpler than they are. There's a point when getting rid of caveats is going to be sacrificing accuracy, so you'd be getting answers that are simplified to the point where they're wrong. I'm not willing to give wrong answers.

Comment: "Redirecting all three of stdin/stdout/stderr and then arranging to ignore SIGHUP is simple, and it's how this has always been done. It's exactly what nohup does, f/e. It's two lines, one for the exec and one for the trap. Nothing hard about it." @Charles Duffy The trap had to be recalled in the code. "Redirecting all three of stdin/stdout/stderr" needs an external file. SIIIIIIIIIMPLE. Something like to write "nohup" at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've explained it in comments, your real goal is to let your script still run in the foreground by default, but make sure it survives SSH disconnecting.

You can do this without needing `disown` in any way, though the code needs to be put at the *top*, not the *bottom*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# redirect all three of stdin, stdout and stderr (not just stdout!)
exec >"txt$$.txt" 2>"err$$.txt" </dev/null

# ignore any SIGHUP signals received
trap : SIGHUP

# ...put the content of your script here
```

Comment: \\\\///// ah. ok. I didn't know that `trap : SIGHUP` it's does not to be recalled. And i also didn't know that `exec >"txt$$.txt" 2>"err$$.txt" </dev/null` makes all the work. Best answer 4 u   HIIIIIIIIIIIIIII 